# Can you connect to the internet via a wired connection from iPad to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, network

I connected my iPhone to my iPad using Apple’s Lightning to USB 3 Photo adapter. I went to settings on my iPad and saw an Ethernet section had appeared. My iPhone shows up there, but it doesn’t seem to do anything. I tried turning WiFi off on my iPad and turning on my hotspot on my iPhone; my iPad couldn’t connect to the internet.

Is it possible for an iPad to connect to the internet via a wired connection to my iPhone? If not, why does my iPhone show up under the Ethernet section of settings on my iPad?

[image: iPhone appearing inside the Ethernet section of settings on my iPad]